# Why does 'je nach' means 'depending on'? Its components have completely different meaning

Tags: preposition

*Je* means *per*, *nach* means *to*.

How can *je nach* mean *depending on*? What is the logic? Or is there any?

Comment: _"nach means to"_ There are more meanings for _nach_.

Comment: Specifically, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nach#Preposition, meaning 4.

Comment: What is your example sentence? Something like *Je nach Appetit mache ich mir ein Käsebrot oder stelle mich an den Herd?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*»Nach«* also has other meanings:

In a restaurant, in the menu you sometimes can read things like this:

> - Gratinierter Fisch
>     **nach** Art des Hauses

The phrase *»nach Art des Hauses«* can be translated as *"house style"* or *"home made"*. It means, that the chef of the restaurant has developed his own recipe, and that you will get this fish nowhere else prepared like here.

So, *»nach«* can indicate a special kind of doing something.

> Der Fisch schmeckt unterschiedlich, je nach Zubereitung.
>   The fish tastes different per each kind of preparation.

---

btw:

There are much more meanings of "nach" (*je nach Kontext,* i.e. depending on context) like

> after, for, to, on, ...
>
> In bin auf der Suche **nach** Antworten.
>   I'm in search **of** answers.
>
> Er hat die Stadt **nach** Osten hin verlassen.
>   He left the town **toward** east.
>
> Es ist 10 Minuten **nach** 9 Uhr.
>   It is 10 **past** 9.

Please consult sites like [dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/nach).

Also *je* has other translations:

> **Je** größer, desto besser.
>   **The** bigger, the better.
>
> Warst du **je** in China?
>   Have you **ever** been in China?

Comment: The last example „warst du je in China“ is incorrect. In this case, „je“ is the shortened version of jemals, which is a different word than „je“ with a totally different meaning.

Comment: @Snailshell: A word that is a shortened version of another word is still a word. And a sentence, that uses this short word, still is a correct sentence. So, *»warst du je in China«* is an absolutely correct German sentence. You also can interpret this usage of *je* as a synonym of *überhaupt* (Warst du überhaupt in China?) which does not work as well with the long word *jemals.* See also *Bedeutung 1* in https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/je#Adverb

Comment: @snailshell that's not helpful. *jemals* is more or less a combination *je* + *mal* + *-s*; *je in china* is likely not an elipses, as much as *nie* isn't eliding *niemals*, and it's likely the original form. *-mals* fills the slot in preverbial positions that *in* takes here, or *ge-* in *hast du je geliebt*; this does leave no usecase for jemals as far as I'm concerned, except perhaps *er hat nie mals wollen*, a form not current in the north; cp *Ersttäter*, *erstmaligetäter* but not *erste Täter*.

Answer (score 2):

Because „je“ and „nach“ can imply that things are different, like different sort of categories, so that is why „je nach“ says „depending on (the characteristic / category)“. „Je“ is also often used as a short form for „jeweils“, though it would be grammatically incorrect to exchange those without changing other parts of the sentence.

A few examples:
„Nimm dir einen Apfel *je* Sorte“ - implies that there are different apples (and you should take one of each)

„Die Äpfel sind sortiert *nach* Farbe“ - the apples are sorted by color

„magst du Äpfel?“ - „je nach Sorte“ -> the answer implies both that there are different kinds of apples, and that you have varying opinions on those.

This is way too formal, but basically „je nach Sorte“ says: „wenn ich Äpfel *nach* Sorten kategorisiere, habe ich *jeweils* andere Meinungen.“

Another example: „gehst du gerne Laufen?“ - „je nach Wetter“: there are different weathers to consider (=nach Wetter) and you have different preferences for each (=je(weils)) depending on how much you would like to be outside under those weather conditions.

Answer (score 0):

### "Je" and "nach" can have very different meanings. It all depends on **context**.

1. For instance, if someone says "**Je nachdem**." he probably means "**It

   depends**."
2. If you say "100 Dollar **je** Stück", it means "100$ **per**
   item" or "100$ apiece".
3. It could also mean "ever" like in "Wirst du
   dich **je** ändern?" = "Will you **ever** change?".

---

**"nach"** has also a lot of different meaning depending on context.

1. **"nach"** = "after" (like in "after supper" = "nach dem Abendessen")
2. **"nach"** = "as per" or "according to" (like in "nach Ihrer Aussage" = "according to you")
3. **"nach"** = "towards" ("nach Hamburg" = "towards Hamburg")
4. **"nach"** = "like" ("nach Rosen duften" = "smell like roses")

---

It is not uncommon for words to change meaning on context. Every language I know behaves this way, German and also English are no exception. 
Just look at the verb "to depend (on)". 
It can mean "abhängig sein von jemand oder etwas" or, if followed by "whether" it would mean "darauf ankommen (ob)".

Words do not always have the same meaning. Sometimes they change meaning because of other words, sometimes they just change because of different time or location. Sometimes they just change because the intention of the writer or speaker has changed (ie. irony). ;)

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question at all.

Comment: Yes, it does. .

Comment: You are talking only separately about *»je«* and *»nach«.* Nowhere in your posting you addressed the phrase *»je nach«.* I can't see an explanation of the meaning of *»je nach«* in yout posting. So, you posting is not an answer of the question.